# getting started with making event-driven applications in Dev C++

Tags: c++

I am a newb developing **a windows C/C++ program in Dev C++** that logs system activity when the link is down.  **I want to get acquainted with developing event-driven applications.**

To learn, I am making a **simpler** program that

1-- does a *ping_a_server()* periodically and thus knows the state of the link

2--a do nothing in the normal state

2--b appends a file with "SERIALNO,TIME" periodically as long as the link is down

2--c sends the file when the link is back up

I am a newb, unfamiliar with real-life programs. Please tell me how to implement the above components 1 and 2 (threads, maybe?) and point me to resources to learn them.

Comment: Havent <i>tried</i> anything as such. I just chose DevC and libCURL. I am a newb yet to get his feet wet. libCURL has great examples: 15 lines to upload a file. I need similar example tutes/code for threading and events.

Comment: Accepted your answer because the .edu sites in the wikipedia page were great. But please point me to example code too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably start with the resources listed on this Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming

Comment: I have trouble accepting your answer. Those .edu sites in the wikipedia page were great.